# mongoose Aggregation returns empty array []?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**$out *stage***

> According to the mongodb documentation

| $out | Writes the resulting documents of the aggregation pipeline to a collection. To use the $out stage, it must be the last stage in the pipeline. |
| --- | --- |

the **$out** stage is working perfectly and writing new collection, i'm using **append** function

> `.append({ $out: "aggr_out" })`

to place it in the last stage.

**The current behavior**

- Saving new collection to the database
- Returning an empty array in the `callback`  function

**Expected behavior**

- Return the aggregate result

**Versions of Node.js, Mongoose, and MongoDB**

- node.js  **v14.17.3 (LTS)**
- mongoose **v5.13.13**
- mongoDB

  - db version **v4.0.23**
  - git version: **07c6611b38d2aacbdb1846b688db70b3273170fb**
  - build environment:

    - distmod: **debian92**
    - distarch: **x86_64**
    - target_arch: **x86_64**

**Code**
[image: aggregate]

Comment: you want to wirte to a new collection and also return you the data? if you want this one simple solution would be to query the newly created collection.

Comment: @Takis_, yes this is simple, but i query the database twice !

Comment: yes ok, but the data are tranfered only once to you, i don't think that you can out+return cursor with one query the same time.

Comment: @Takis_ , yes indeed, I'm querying the newly created collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the expected behavior; i.e., when you use the `$out` stage in an aggregation query the result of the query is written to the collection name specified in the `$out`. And, the query returns an *empty* cursor.

For example, take a collection with a document:

```
{ _id: 1, stuff: [ "bananas", "whales" ] }
```

The query:

```
var cur = db.collection.aggregate([
    { $out: "new_collection" }
])
```

When you run this query (in `mongo` shell), the console output is an empty cursor (though the `new_collection` is created).

`cur.hasNext()` returns `false` (indicates there are no result documents in the cursor).

Mongoose query returns an array (not a cursor). So, you see an empty array in the callback result value. This is to be expected.

**Reference**: [db.collection.aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) - see the *Returns* section.

> If the pipeline includes the $out operator, aggregate() returns an
> empty cursor.

Comment: The above query was run on a MongoDB v4.2.8 server and `mongo` shell client.

Comment: I didn't notice that the documentation mention this,
thank you @prasad_